# How to pass all checkbox id's to jQuery change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Here I am passing one checkbox ID like `filter_AFFILIATION_1` then O am getting this checkbox ID result.

How can I pass all check box ID's (`filter_AFFILIATION_1`, `filter_AFFILIATION_2`, `filter_AFFILIATION_3`, `filter_AFFILIATION_4`) at a time above javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filter_AFFILIATION_1").change(function() {
    var data = {
      request: $('#filter_AFFILIATION_1').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: Routing.generate('listingpage'),
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      data: data,
      success: function(result, status, xhr) {
        var div_options = document.getElementById("filter_AFFILIATION_1");
        var inst_arr = JSON.parse(result);
        var inst_val_arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < inst_arr.length; i++) {
          inst_val_arr[i] = inst_arr[i];
          var affiliation = inst_val_arr[i].instaffiliation;

          document.getElementById('aff').innerHTML = affiliation;

          if (document.getElementById('filter_AFFILIATION_1').checked) {
            $('#schooldata').html('');
          } else if (!(document.getElementById('filter_AFFILIATION_1').checked)) {
            alert('nothing');
          }
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="filter_AFFILIATION_1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="filter_AFFILIATION_1" name="filter_AFFILIATION_1[]" value="1">ICSE
    </label>
<label for="filter_AFFILIATION_2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="filter_AFFILIATION_2" name="filter_AFFILIATION_2[]" value="2">CBSE
    </label>
<label for="filter_AFFILIATION_3">
    <input type="checkbox" id="filter_AFFILIATION_3" name="filter_AFFILIATION_3[]" value="3">State Board
    </label>
<label for="filter_AFFILIATION_4">
    <input type="checkbox" id="filter_AFFILIATION_4" name="filter_AFFILIATION_4[]" value="4">ISC
    </label>
```

Comment: Use a class instead.  $('.filter_AFFILIATION') and go get coffee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make data as array `data=[]` and then push your values in it. Then in ajax `data: data` will send whole array. On the server you will get ids as `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]` and so on.

ok. i suggest making class for all check boxes and then get all id from that class like

```
var data= [];
    $('.filter_AFFILIATIONS').each(function () {
      data.push(this.id)
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response everyone i am new to these concept how can i use document.getElementById("filter_AFFILIATION_1"); instead of id

Comment: Can you be more clear. Do as i understand, is your goal to send all checkbox information to server with ajax right? Or. Do you want to send checkbox ids names as text?

Comment: yes i want to send all checkbox id s to ajax request

Comment: i tried to sending data as an array but response is not getting i think i did mistake somewhere

Comment: var data = {request : $('#filter_AFFILIATION_1').val()}; this is dictionary if you had not changed yet, request is key you don't need it.
ithis is how you can do it
var data = []
then use function above
and then in ajax 
data : data

Answer (score 0):

Use `^=` in an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). This will let you select every input element who's `id` begins with `filter_AFFILATION`.

```
$('input[id^="filter_AFFILATION"]').change(function(){...});
```